# How do I tell qmake about a directory of source files?

Tags: qt, qmake

I have a folder where my sources (`*.cpp`) are. How can I tell qmake to look there for sources? I don't want to write the full path for every `.cpp` file.

For include files, I can say:

```
INCLUDEPATH += /path/to/include/files
```

Is there something similar for source files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is VPATH.

> **[VPATH](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#vpath)**
>
> Tells qmake where to search for files it cannot open. For example, if
>   qmake looks for SOURCES and finds an entry that it cannot open, it
>   looks through the entire VPATH list to see if it can find the file on
>   its own.

Comment: Thank you! Do you happen to know a similar option for standard Makefile and for cmake?

Comment: @SamerAfach You can use VPATH in Makefiles as well. See [VPATH: Search Path for All Prerequisites](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#General-Search). I've never worked with cmake so I can not answer that.